# Acked is zero with Word Count Topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm new to storm , i submitted storm-starter project , Word-count Topology

i got 
[image: wordcount]

Acked is zero ! How can i fix it ?

The link of the code for anyone don't know the project

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java

```java
package storm.starter;

import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseBasicBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import storm.starter.spout.RandomSentenceSpout;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This topology demonstrates Storm's stream groupings and multilang capabilities.
 */
public class WordCountTopology {
  public static class SplitSentence extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {

    public SplitSentence() {
      super("python", "splitsentence.py");
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static class WordCount extends BaseBasicBolt {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
      String word = tuple.getString(0);
      Integer count = counts.get(word);
      if (count == null)
        count = 0;
      count++;
      counts.put(word, count);
      collector.emit(new Values(word, count));
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("word", "count"));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("spout", new RandomSentenceSpout(), 5);

    builder.setBolt("split", new SplitSentence(), 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");
    builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), 12).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("word"));

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);


    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
      conf.setNumWorkers(3);

      StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
    else {
      conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("word-count", conf, builder.createTopology());

      Thread.sleep(10000);

      cluster.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the present code from your Topology?

Comment: storm-starter is a famous example for storm so everyone dealed with storm know it well ! why you downvote ??!! you just need code and i'll post it ?!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but per Stackoverflow guidelines, you're suppose to provide code samples. So in your best interest, you should probably follow those guidelines. That's probably why someone else downvoted you.

Comment: sorry for my question but i know that everyone know storm have good background on this project . sorry again

Answer (score 0):

To get tuple acking in Storm, a couple things are required.

1. Make sure you enable ackers by setting the Topology_Ackers_Executors configuration.

   ```
   //in java
   conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_ACKER_EXECUTORS, 2);
   //in storm.yaml
   topology.acker.executors: 2  //defaults to 0
   ```

   You only have to set the configuration in one of those two places. storm.yaml is the default and Java configuration can override anything in storm.yaml.
2. [Tuple Anchoring](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) in Bolt

   ```
   //short java snippet
   String sentence = tuple.getString(0);
   for(String word: sentence.split(" ")) {
     _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(word)); //anchoring
     _collector.emit(new Values(word));        //not anchoring
   }
   _collector.ack(tuple);
   ```

   As described in the link above. You have to anchor tuples together for acking to be enabled. In the first `collector.emit`, your anchoring the newly created tuple `new Values(word)` to the old tuple. But in the second `collector.emit`, your not anchoring the tuple. Tuples need to be anchored to each other for acking to work. I don't know how to do that in Python, so you'll have to figure that out.

There could possible be other things you need to do, this answer is mostly from memory and I haven't tested out any of your code. But this should give you a starting point. If you have any problems, read the [documentation](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) before asking another low quality question. That is how I figured it out, and you should probably learn to develop that skill too.

Comment: First thanks for your illustration . it is supposed for this project to work well without any errors ad it worked already with other people without any problems . so I asked as i'm not the coder or this project supposed to work well and as I'm new I asked because it may be something I don't know didn't set it in the property , i'm searching before ask here and hope to get solution without asking but couldn't find thing , but thanks to you !

Comment: I apologize if I sounded harsh. As a site stackoverflow has guidelines for asking questions, and you didn't seem to abide by those guidelines. Your original question sounded very much like a 'gimme teh codez' type question. Asking bad quality questions on stackoverflow is probably one of the quickest ways to not get a very good answer, if one at all. It didn't seem like you put any effort into asking the question or attempting to figure out the answer for yourself. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question

Comment: i searched before i posted here but didn't find anything except one post and tried the sollution on it but problem still ! so i asked here to get help from expert people in storm and asked also in storm-user and storm-dev and tried to try topology.acker.executors: 2  without any changes

Comment: Are you anchoring your tuples in Python?

Comment: no all code in java , but i've another question if you don't mind , should i have numbers in columns in storm ui without click show system stats or is must click on it to get numbres ?

Comment: did you submit topology before ? i mean the numbers in column of transeferred and emitted appeared once you access storm ui ? or you click the button that in storm ui